# Android & SDL: "called unimplemented OpenGL ES API"

Tags: android, opengl-es, sdl, android-ndk

I'm trying to run the ["Alien Shooter" Android/SDL example](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/android-project.zip) on my new [Samsung Galaxy Fit](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_fit_s5670-3726.php). I have not changed any of the code from its initial state. On the emulator things work fine but on the real device, I get a black screen and:

> "libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API"

over and over again in Logcat. The only difference between the two that I can make out is that the emulator attempts to create a GLES 2.0 Context but fails:

> "SDL: No EGL config available"

at which point it tries again, this time successfully with GLES 1.1. The Hardware, on the other hand, doesn't fail the first time so sticks with version 2. I've tried forcing it to choose GLES 1.1 from the beginning, but this just crashes the App altogether, both on the emulator and on the hardware.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be solved by forcing the use of OpenGLES1.1 rather than 2.0. In addition, newer versions of SDL 1.3 now support OpenGLES2.0 as well - see here:
http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1291

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your program cannot find the library. It is trying to use a defined function that has no implementation, which would be in the library.